# How to pass in two different variables to ng directive using angular?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I am trying to create a password validation directive but I run into a couple of problems. Here is a [jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/ys7mpoh6/54/)

1. When I enter one input box, the other input box automatically updates, it shouldn't do that
2. I don't know how to pass in the value of the second input to the directive

Here is my html

```
<form name="sampleForm">
    <input name="strongSecret" type="text" ng-model="strongSecret" strong-secret required placeholder="Please provide password">
    <ul class="error-msgs" ng-messages="sampleForm.strongSecret.$error">
        <li ng-message="numberValidator">Strong secret has to contain at least 1 number</li>
        <li ng-message="uppercaseValidator">Strong secret has to contain at least 1 uppercase</li>
        <li ng-message="sixCharactersValidator">Strong secret has to exactly 6 characters long</li>
    </ul>

    <input name="strongSecret" type="text" ng-model="strongSecret" strong-secret required placeholder="Please confirm password">
    <ul class="error-msgs" ng-messages="sampleForm.strongSecret.$error">
        <li ng-message="numberValidator">Strong secret has to contain at least 1 number</li>
        <li ng-message="uppercaseValidator">Strong secret has to contain at least 1 uppercase</li>
        <li ng-message="sixCharactersValidator">Strong secret has to exactly 6 characters long</li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

Here is my js file

```
angular.module('app', ['ngMessages']);
angular.module('app').directive('strongSecret', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, element, attr, ctrl) {

            function customValidator(ngModelValue, ngModelValue2) {
                // only ngModelValue returns
                console.log(ngModelValue);
                // this is undefined
                console.log(ngModelValue2);
                if (/[A-Z]/.test(ngModelValue)) {
                    ctrl.$setValidity('uppercaseValidator', true);
                } else {
                    ctrl.$setValidity('uppercaseValidator', false);
                }

                return ngModelValue;
            }
            ctrl.$parsers.push(customValidator);
        }
    };
});
```

When `customValidator` runs, it seems like the second parameter never populates.

Can someone give me a hint to solve the problem.

Thanks

Edit:

I created a new validator for the second input, but now I run into a different set of problem [(jsfiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/ys7mpoh6/57/)

1. When I enter input box 1, the validator doesn't work
2. When I enter input box 2, both validator works

I suspect that I am not creating the binding necessary between input 1 and validator 1 and input 2 and validator 2

Answer (score 0):

Both your text inputs are referring to the same model, which is why they both update when you type into one of them. You should try changing the second one's model (and name) attribute to strongSecretConfirm or something similar.

Your validator should run on the first field only.
You will want a second validator that validates that strongSecretConfirm is equal to strongSecret.

Comment: How do you bind validators to the input form? I tried creating another validator with different `$setValidity` name but the binding between the form and the new input in lacking

Comment: Weird. It looks like there's a naming clash when using strongSecret as both your input field name and model name. I used underscore-case for the field name and it is working:
[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/ys7mpoh6/61/)